# mv `Argument list too long` for a single file

Tags: files, osx, bugs, vfat

I was trying to move a set of 7 files to my computer, via `mv g* dir`.  The command line moved 6 of them, and for the last file gave the following error:

```
mv: g.tex: Argument list too long
```

Since the other files, both those before and after it, are already moved, I tried `mv g.tex dir`.  Same error.  Moving other files works fine.  (Note: `g.tex` is a file, not a directory.)

Update: Renaming the file via `mv` also works fine; moving it to another directory on the USB drive also works fine.  However, even when I rename it, or move it to another directory on the USB drive, I still cannot move it to my computer.

I tried to `cat` this file, to copy its contents to the desktop:

`cat: g.tex: Argument list too long`

What else might be causing this problem?

Update: after comparing output of `dtruss` with a file which successfully moved, here are the lines of the log which differ:

```
read(0x3, "\0", 0x20000)         = -1 Err#7
write_nocancel(0x2, "mv: \0", 0x4)       = 4 0
getrlimit(0x1008, 0x7FFF5A00BC78, 0x4)       = 0 0
write_nocancel(0x2, "g.tex\0", 0x5)      = 5 0
write_nocancel(0x2, ": \0", 0x2)         = 2 0
write_nocancel(0x2, "Argument list too long\n\0", 0x17)      = 23 0
unlink("/Users/username/Desktop/Tex/g.tex\0", 0x7FFF5A00B8A0, 0x17)      = 0 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
```

From the list of Unix error codes for `read`:

```
#define E2BIG        7  /* Argument list too long */
```

On a successful move, it displays instead:

```
read(0x3, "Beginning of file contents...", 0x20000)      = 0 0
fstat64_extended(0x3, 0x7FF1F5C02568, 0x7FF1F5C02660)        = 0 0
fstat64(0x4, 0x7FFF5A653EF0, 0x7FF1F5C02660)         = 0 0
fchmod(0x4, 0x180, 0x7FF1F5C02660)       = 0 0
__mac_syscall(0x7FFF8E670D02, 0x52, 0x7FFF5A653E70)      = -1 Err#93
flistxattr(0x4, 0x0, 0x0)        = 0 0
flistxattr(0x3, 0x0, 0x0)        = 23 0
flistxattr(0x3, 0x7FF1F5C02490, 0x17)        = 23 0
fgetxattr(0x3, 0x7FF1F5C02490, 0x0)      = 11 0
fgetxattr(0x3, 0x7FF1F5C02490, 0x7FF1F6001000)       = 11 0
fsetxattr(0x4, 0x7FF1F5C02490, 0x7FF1F6001000)       = 0 0
fstat64_extended(0x4, 0x7FFF5A653628, 0x7FF1F5C02660)        = 0 0
fchmod_extended(0x4, 0xFFFFFF9B, 0xFFFFFF9B)         = 0 0
fchmod(0x4, 0x0, 0xFFFFFF9B)         = 0 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
fchown(0x4, 0x6300000063, 0x63)      = 0 0
fchmod(0x4, 0x81FF, 0x63)        = 0 0
fchflags(0x4, 0x0, 0x63)         = 0 0
utimes("/Users/aleksander/Desktop/Tex/new_filename\0", 0x7FFF5A654860, 0x63)         = 0 0
```

Just in case this helps, the remainder of the lines, which match for a successful `mv` command and for the failed one, right before the differing text quoted above:

```
open("/dev/dtracehelper\0", 0x2, 0x7FFF53E619B0)         = 3 0
ioctl(0x3, 0x80086804, 0x7FFF53E61938)       = 0 0
close(0x3)       = 0 0
thread_selfid(0x3, 0x80086804, 0x7FFF53E61938)       = 167920154 0
bsdthread_register(0x7FFF8E8710F4, 0x7FFF8E8710E4, 0x2000)       = 1073741919 0
ulock_wake(0x1, 0x7FFF53E6116C, 0x0)         = -1 Err#2
issetugid(0x1, 0x7FFF53E6116C, 0x0)      = 0 0
mprotect(0x10BDA5000, 0x88, 0x1)         = 0 0
mprotect(0x10BDA7000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x10BDBD000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x10BDBE000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x10BDD4000, 0x1000, 0x0)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x10BDD5000, 0x1000, 0x1)       = 0 0
mprotect(0x10BDA5000, 0x88, 0x3)         = 0 0
mprotect(0x10BDA5000, 0x88, 0x1)         = 0 0
getpid(0x10BDA5000, 0x88, 0x1)       = 28838 0
stat64("/AppleInternal/XBS/.isChrooted\0", 0x7FFF53E61028, 0x1)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/AppleInternal\0", 0x7FFF53E610C0, 0x1)      = -1 Err#2
csops(0x70A6, 0x7, 0x7FFF53E60B50)       = 0 0
sysctl([CTL_KERN, 14, 1, 28838, 0, 0] (4), 0x7FFF53E60CA8, 0x7FFF53E60CA0, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0
ulock_wake(0x1, 0x7FFF53E610D0, 0x0)         = -1 Err#2
csops(0x70A6, 0x7, 0x7FFF53E60430)       = 0 0
stat64("/Users/aleksander/Desktop/Tex\0", 0x7FFF53E62B88, 0x7FFF53E60430)    = 0 0
lstat64("g.tex\0", 0x7FFF53E62AF8, 0x7FFF53E60430)       = 0 0
lstat64("/Users/aleksander/Desktop/Tex\0", 0x7FFF53E62A68, 0x7FFF53E60430)   = 0 0
stat64("g.tex\0", 0x7FFF53E62AF8, 0x7FFF53E60430)        = 0 0
stat64("/Users/aleksander/Desktop/Tex/g.tex\0", 0x7FFF53E62A68, 0x7FFF53E60430) = -1 Err#2
access("/Users/aleksander/Desktop/Tex/g.tex\0", 0x0, 0x7FFF53E60430)         = -1 Err#2
rename("g.tex\0", "/Users/aleksander/Desktop/Tex/g.tex\0")       = -1 Err#18
stat64("/\0", 0x7FFF53E5FB60, 0x7FFF53E60430)        = 0 0
open_nocancel(".\0", 0x0, 0x1)       = 3 0
fstat64(0x3, 0x7FFF53E5F900, 0x1)        = 0 0
fcntl_nocancel(0x3, 0x32, 0x7FFF53E61980)        = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x3)      = 0 0
stat64("/Volumes/NO NAME\0", 0x7FFF5A00A870, 0x7FFF5A00C980)         = 0 0
stat64("/Volumes/NO NAME\0", 0x7FFF5A00AB60, 0x7FFF5A00C980)         = 0 0
getattrlist("/Volumes/NO NAME/g.tex\0", 0x7FFF8E715B04, 0x7FFF5A00C470)      = 0 0
statfs64(0x7FFF5A00C980, 0x7FFF5A00CD88, 0x7FFF5A00C470)         = 0 0
lstat64("g.tex\0", 0x7FFF5A00C8F0, 0x7FFF5A00C470)       = 0 0
open("g.tex\0", 0x0, 0x0)        = 3 0
open("/Users/aleksander/Desktop/Tex/g.tex\0", 0xE01, 0x0)        = 4 0
fstatfs64(0x4, 0x7FFF5A00BFF8, 0x0)      = 0 0
```

`xattr -l g.tex` doesn't give any output.
`ls -l g.tex` yields:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 username staff 159939 Aug 15 11:54 g.tex
```

`mount` yields:

```
/dev/disk5s1 on /Volumes/NO NAME (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
```

Comment: You likely have filenames with `-` in them, or some other special character.  Try `mv -- g* dir`

Comment: Nope, no filenames with special characters.  Your suggestion still yielded the same error.

Comment: Try to `ls | cat` to be sure, maybe it has a line break in the filename?

Comment: @Jesse_b I just tried that-- all these files are ones I created by hand, so wouldn't have that.

Comment: Do you know the total number of files you are trying to move?

Comment: @Jesse_b Just 1.  The other 6 moved successfully.

Comment: You might use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), perhaps as `strace mv`, to understand what system call is giving `E2BIG` as [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). You should **edit your question** to give the *exact* command which failed; you could also replace `mv` by `echo` to understand how is `g*` expanded

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `strace: command not found`; on a Mac.

Comment: Then use `dtruss`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch OK, done.

Comment: What's the output of ls -l g.tex

Comment: What type of filesystem is the source file `g.tex` on? Can you run `mount` and show us the line that contains the filesystem's mount options?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but what does `lsattr g.tex` or `getfattr g.tex` say?

Comment: Does `xattr -l g.tex` show a super long value for any of the attributes?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `xattr -l g.tex` doesn't give any output.  `mount` yields: `/dev/disk5s1 on /Volumes/NO NAME (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)`

Comment: @DrEval `-rwxrwxrwx  1 username  staff  159939 Aug 15 11:54 g.tex`

Comment: @JohanMyréen Neither one of these commands exists on a Mac...

Comment: Can you upload the entire output from dtruss somewhere?

Comment: @Henrik I went ahead, and edited the question to include it.  It wasn't that much more, than what I originally had...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

E2BIG is not one of the errors that [`read(2)`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/read.2.html) may return. It looks like a bug in the kernel.

Pure speculation, but it could be down to some corruption on the file system and the macOS driver for the FAT filesystem returning that error upon encountering that corruption which eventually makes it through to the return of `read`.

In any case, it looks like you've taken the investigation as far as it gets. Going further would require dissecting the file system and the kernel driver code.

You could have a look at the kernel logs to see if there's more information there. You could try mounting the FS on a different OS. Or use the GNU `mtools` to access that FAT filesystem.

You could also report the problem to Apple as at least a documentation issue (to include E2BIG as one of the possible error codes, and the conditions upon which it may be returned).

Comment: @Alex, issue `man 2 read` on your system.  Towards the bottom of the manual page should be a list of all possible `errno` values, and the conditions under which that `errno` will be set.

Comment: What would I do, once I access that FS via mtools? Which kernel logs would contain info about this? I am curious to get down to the bottom of this...

Answer (score 2):

Figured out how to solve this.  I installed GNU `mv`, via macPorts.  That `mv` was able to move the file from the USB drive to my computer, without returning the E2BIG error.  I wish I would have `dtruss`ed it, to see how it got around the error return from the `read`.

It turned out that the file pointer was slightly corrupted-- so, the file that got copied started 128KB earlier than where it *should* have started, but the rest of the file was intact (of course, the last 128KB also got chopped off.)

Lesson to be learned: the native (BSD) utilities on a Mac run a different algorithm than their GNU counterparts-- so when one fails, always try the other.

Comment: GNU `mv` will do `read()s` and `write()s` just the same. Given that the default chunk size is 128K, I suspect it just ignored the error of the first read() (if it did without reporting an error, I would call that a bug)

Comment: That would be a logical explanation if the result was the file starting at position 128K.  However, the result was the file starting at position *negative* 128K.  So basically, 128K of junk, and then the file, minus the last 128K of it (since the filesize had to remain the same).

Comment: I'm not sure what's the bigger bug-- `read` returning E2BIG, or not reporting an error when there is one so unexpected.  :-)

Comment: Anyway, `read()` returns the number of bytes read. `mv` **has** to take that number into account. It's hard to imagine that it could mistakenly take `-1` as meaning _a full buffer was read_ (as if it was 131072) and write the buffer (with whatever garbage was in it) to the destination file. Possibly on macOS GNU `mv` uses `mmap()` or some macOS-specific way to read the data that triggers a different bug. Can you try `dtruss mv` on a test file to see how it copies the data across?

Comment: In addition to the `read` commands of the BSD mv, it also has the following: `sysctl([CTL_HW, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0] (2), 0x7FFF9754DE00, 0x7FFF56608570, 0x0, 0x0)  = 0 0`, `madvise(0x10976A000, 0x21000, 0x9)   = 0 0`, `lseek(0x0, 0x0, 0x1)   = 221838 0`, `close_nocancel(0x0)   = 0 0`, and a few similar commands.  Not sure which of these would make the difference...